# Convert tuple of list to list

Tags: python, list, tuples

Below is the tuple I'm using:

```
tupleA = ([{'std_name':'A','std_addr':'Peachtree Drive'},{'std_name':'B','std_addr':'Alameda Drive'}],)
```

I want it to convert into a single list of dict which would look like this -

```
myList = [{'std_name':'A','std_addr':'Peachtree Drive'},{'std_name':'B','std_addr':'Alameda Drive'}]
```

what is the best approach to convert this tuple?

Comment: Why do you have tuple of list? Is it coming from any external source and what is current status of your work

Comment: If I understood you correctly, this should be all you need to do: `myList = tupleA[0]`

Comment: The tuple is coming from an external API and our system needs a list to iterate the dictionary items inside.

Comment: Then @ZiyadCodes answer should work right

Comment: Yup, it worked!! Thanks, @ZiyadCodes If you put it into the answer, I'll mark it as solved.  I was trying this iterator thingy that wasn't working great!

Comment: You could potentially already unpack it where you assigned it in the first place. Would be less code/work. Can't tell without seeing that code.

Comment: The issue is external system did an upgrade and suddenly started sending the tuple instead of the list. So, this solution provided works perfectly with just a single line of code change. I hope they don't revert to sending list again :)

Comment: Adding a single line of code is still more than adding a single *comma*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it looks like you want the element inside the tuple, so if you do this:

```
myList = tupleA[0]
```

You'll get the list inside the tuple